# Interact with NFC reader in Windows 10 Assigned Access mode

Tags: uwp, nfc, proximity, kiosk-mode

I'm developing UWP app with NFC reader interactions. App is running in Windows 10 Assigned Access mode.

I use NTAG213 and NTAG216 tags. This is how I init device:

```
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
....
private ProximityDevice _device;
public void InitNFCDevice() =>
        _device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
```

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ashchuk/84c4b5eeca341a157099004a2d4c8243).
Here is a [test app](https://github.com/ashchuk/NFCTestApp) with same problem, I tested it on my tablet.

And all works fine, but not then Assigned Access turned on.

Then I turn Assigned Access on and launching app, `_device` is not `null`, but when I try to, for example, read a tag, nothing happens. The tablet must sing a sound if the tag is near reader, but it doesn't work.

I checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/assigned-access) link and after checking settings to turn on Radio and Other devices access nothing was changed.

Maybe there is an another checkbox or setting what I have not found? Or maybe something else? I have no ideas now.

I repeat that in normal mode everything works, but not in Assigned Access.

**EDIT:**

Found also this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access) about Kiosk-mode best practices.

Using this:

```
await CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    async () => { ... } );
```

instead of this:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    async () => { ... } );
```

not worked too.

And some info about my OS version. I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 10240.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I turn Assigned Access on and launching app, _device is not null,
>   but when I try to, for example, read a tag, nothing happens. The
>   tablet must sing a sound if the tag is near reader, but it doesn't
>   work.

Thank you for reporting this issue, we have not covered this scenario in testing cases. If this issue still always happen in RS2 and the latest insider preview version(Fast Ring), the related team will investigate it.

----Update----

Please collect OS traces while trying out the scenario. Instructions for collecting OS traces are as follows:

1. From an elevated cmd prompt, run:
   netsh trace start WirelessDisplay globallevel=0xff persistent = yes
2. Repro the issue.
3. netsh trace stop
4. Send the resulting files back for investigation.

You can send me the email with logs, please check my profile for contact information.

Comment: Thanks, Franklin! I'll add some additional info about OS I'm using

Comment: @ashchuk I updated some steps for collecting logs, could you please help us to get the log files? If so, please check my profile and send email to me:)

Comment: How can I start ```cmd``` in kiosk if it's only my app allowed to start?